# Getting all ordered sublists of ordered lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

We are struggling with the following problem:
For example  the following list, should be divided in `m` lists with the same order.

Lets say `[9,7,6,5,2,10,8,4,3,1]` with `m=3`
a few of the end results should be:

```
[[9],[7,6],[5,2,10,8,4,3,1]]
[[9,7],[6,5,2,10,8,4,3],[1]]
[[9,7,6,5],[2,10,8,4],[3,1]]
```

etc.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried, what errors are you getting?

Comment: See this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements/24402296)

Comment: @prashantrana This solution doesn't take the order into account.

Comment: @Stijin that was hint . Create a nested list of size 3 and using this  link put values in that .

Comment: What is the statement of your problem? I can read that you're going to declare it, but then you start with an example.

Comment: @Gsk  We want to have all the possible permutations of a list, but with respect to the order. I thought the example would clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations


perm=[]
index = [9,7,6,5,2,10,8,4,3,1]
perm.append(index)
M = 3
slicer = [x for x in combinations(range(1, len(index)), M - 1)]
slicer = [(0,) + x + (len(index),) for x in slicer]

result = [tuple(p[s[i]:s[i + 1]] for i in range(len(s) - 1)) for s in slicer for p in perm]
```

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

n= length of the list

k=m=3

```
def part(n, k):
 def _part(n, k, pre):
    if n <= 0:
        return []
    if k == 1:
        if n <= pre:
            return [[n]]
        return []
    ret = []
    for i in range(min(pre, n), 0, -1):
        ret += [[i] + sub for sub in _part(n-i, k-1, i)]
    return ret
 return _part(n, k, n)

import itertools
perm=[]
partitions=part(n, m)
for i in partitions:
    perm.append(list(itertools.permutations(i,m)))
perm1=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(perm))  
y= [9,7,6,5,2,10,8,4,3]
new=[]
for i in perm1:
   k=0
   for j in i:
       new.append(list(y[k:k+j]))
       k=k+j
       if k==9:
         print(new)
         new=[]
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but do you have any idea how to use itertools.combinations?So we can get all possible combinations out of it? Since I tried a lot with it but it doesn't take order into account.

Comment: Hey , I have updated the code which will print all the possible outputs.